# Gong drag and drop - Touch

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, touch, tablet

I'm using the Gong - Drag and drop solution, which works like a charm on my Windows 7 Machine, but as soon as I transfer the solution to my Surface tablet, and starts to drag and drop, nothing happens when I use my fingers, but when I use my stylus it works.

How do I easily implement the drag and drop with fingers instead, or am I doing something wrong when dragging and dropping.

Comment: Hi Mathias, That is a great question.  I am working with GongSolutions and drag/drop as well.  Did you ever find a solution to making GongSolutions work with touch (fingers)?

Comment: the library seems to be quite hard-coded for mouse events, perhaps answer is to implement touch event handling, and that may be bit broad to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample project with facilities like:

Drag a node and Drop it in another node

Add a node using Context Menu

Rename a node using Context Menu

Delete a node using Context Menu

You can find sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bYmJ4SkEzXzdmUk0/view?usp=sharing).

I have not tried to solve your problem but you can easily add event handlers for touch and make some changes to that sample to do your work.

You can get complete control over the code as I have not used any external libraries in this project.